# Monitor language specific API Calls for Microsoft Translator API

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-translator

Is there any way to monitor the Language Specific USAGE of Translator API (e.g. xx number of characters for `english` to `japanese` for Microsoft Translator API. I couldn't see any such metrics in the Metrics Monitoring Section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it's not available, We have added to Azure metrics feature request to the Translator service and it will be added in the near future.